# How to make many plots, with functions For and Plot?

Tags: list, for-loop, plot, wolfram-mathematica

I need to make several plots and i'm trying to do it with the help of For. 
My data:

```
0.0023709,8.5752e-007,4.847e-008
```

My code:

```
column1 = data[[All,1]]
For[i = 1, i < 4, Plot[column1[[i]]*t, {t, 0, 10}]]
```

After running Mathematica write "Running" and that's all. 
I want make several plots for some lists and export them. Please, help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, using `For` like your code.

```
data = {{1, 0}, {2, 0}, {3, 0}};
output = {};
column1 = data[[All, 1]];
 For[i = 1, i < 4, i++,
  AppendTo[output,
   ListPlot[Table[column1[[i]]*t, {t, 0, 10}]]]]
output
```

Second, an equivalent method.

```
output = Table[ListPlot[Table[column1[[i]]*t, {t, 0, 10}]], {i, 1, 3}]
```

Comment: I modified your code: output = {};
For[i = 1, i < 4, i++, 
 AppendTo[output, Plot[column1[[i]]*t, {t, 0, 10}]]]
output and solve my problem. Thank you!